# Evaluating Double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\iint_R e^{x+y} \, dx \, dy$$ where $R$ is the domain lying between two squares of sides 2 and 4 with centre at origin and sides are parallel to the co-ordinate axes.
I can't understand the limits..please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw  a picture and consider $y$ between $-1$ and $1$, between $1$ and $2$ and between $-2$ and $-1$. Write down the range of values of $x$ in each case.

The integral is $(\int_{-2}^{-1} \int_{-2}^{2} +\int_{1}^{2} \int_{-2}^{2}+\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} )  e^{x+y} dx dy$

Comment: Ok thank you..I understood 